# Is the integral against a Brownian motion conditioned to stay bounded a local martingale?

Tags: pr.probability, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-differential-equations

Let $W$ be a standard Brownian motion on a probability space $(X, \mathcal F, \mathbb P)$ let and $\mathcal F_t$ its natural filtration.

For $\varepsilon > 0, T \in [0, \infty)$ let $A_{\varepsilon, t}$ be the event $\{\sup_{s \in [0, T]} |W_s|\ < \varepsilon\}$.

Let $X_t$ be the solution to the SDE

$$dX_t = \sigma(t, X_t) dW_t$$

where $\sigma$ is nice enough for a solution to exist.

For each $\varepsilon, T$ define the probability measure $\mathbb Q_{\epsilon, T}$ by

$$\mathbb Q_{\varepsilon, t} (E) = \frac{\mathbb P(E \cap A_{\varepsilon, T})}{\mathbb P(A_{\varepsilon, T)}}.$$

> **Question:** Is $X$ a local $\mathcal F_t$ martingale under $\mathbb Q_{\varepsilon, T}$?

**Remark:** We note that $\mathbb Q_{\varepsilon, T}$ is *not* equivalent to $\mathbb P$, so that we cannot apply Girsanov’s theorem.

Comment: Further remark: It seems the discrete time analogy with the standard random walk is not true. I am not sure if being in continuous time changes anything. I’m guessing no, but I am not sure how to rigorously prove it.

Comment: (i) I think there is a typo in your definition of $\mathbb Q_{\varepsilon, t} (E)$ -- there should be $\mathbb P(A_{\varepsilon, t})$ there instead of $\mathbb P(E)$". (ii) What do you mean by "a local $\mathcal F_t$ martingale under $\mathbb Q_{\varepsilon, t}$"?  The probability measure should not depend on $t$.

Comment: Ah, I’ve used $t$ twice, sorry let me modify that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case $\sigma = 1$  the claim is that the conditioned process itself is a martingale, however, as it paths are the paths of a brownian motion, it will have quadratic variation t, and therefore, it is an ordinary brownian motion.

Comment: Will not the quadratic variation change under the change of measure? My intuition is that this has no chance of being a proper martingale, only potentially a local one.

Comment: Oh, of course the process can’t be a standard Brownian motion under $\mathbb Q$ - a standard Brownian motion has a nonzero probability of reaching a value above $\varepsilon$.

Comment: Nate, it won't ever change under any change of measure because it depends on almost sure convergence

Comment: Isn’t it convergence in probability?